# Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined although I have included everything. How to beautify the JSON and XML in textarea

Tags: html, json, xml, textarea, codemirror

`I tried some of the available answers related to the same but none worked hence posting the same`

I am trying format my JSON and XML code in the textarea using the CodeMirror so I have downloaded the CodemIrror zip file and pasted in my project folder. The folder structure looks something like this.

```
Views
  -codemirror (directory with all the folders related to it including lib)
  -index.html
```

In my `ìndex.html` I have included the codemirror:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror/mode/clike/clike.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
```

Also I have the textarea in my Index.html as:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <h5>Test Events in XML :</h5>
   <textarea stryle="height: 400px;" class="form-control" id="xmldata" ng-model="xmldata"></textarea>
</div>
```

in my Javascript file I am simply trying to add the line number to the Textarea using the codemirror but for some reason it fails:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(xmldata, {
    lineNumbers: true
  });
```

When I run the code I get following error in my browser console:

```
homeScript.js:115 Uncaught ReferenceError: CodeMirror is not defined
    at homeScript.js:115
```

How can beautify the XML and JSON data that is present within the Textarea using the CodeMirror

Comment: I tried few more things but still unable to get this thing working.
Can someone please answer this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `"xmldata"` is a handle to an element?
Correct code would look like:

```
var myTextArea=document.getElementById("xmldata");
CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextArea);
```